# Como logar com slf4j de dentro de um módulo do jboss?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, slf4j, jboss-modules

Como eu posso logar para o console / server.log de dentro de um módulo do jboss?

Digamos que eu tenha uma classe:

```
public class MyClass {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    private boolean done = false;

    public void doSomething() {
        logger.info("Look ma, I'm logging!");
        done = true;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return done;
    }
}
```

Se eu quiser logar algo de dentro de um artefato deployado (e.g., `MyWebProject.war`), tudo o que tenho que fazer é:

1. Compilar contra `slf4j-api`

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.7</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Deploy

   ```
   ./jboss-cli.sh -c "deploy  MyWebProject.war"
   ```
3. E pronto

   ```
   2015-10-19 11:04:02,445 INFO  [com.myCompany.MyClass] (default task-13) Look ma, I'm logging!
   ```

---

Mas eu não consigo, de nenhuma maneira, obter o mesmo efeito de dentro de um módulo do jboss.

**Exemplo:** Se `MyWebProject.war` usa `MyModule.jar`, e `MyModule.jar` é deployado como um módulo do jboss:

```
${jbossHome}/modules/com/mycompany/mymodule/main
                                            |____ MyModule.jar
                                            |____ module.xml
```

#### Module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mycompany.mymodule">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="MyModule.jar" />
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="org.slf4j" />
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

Se eu mover `MyClass` para `MyModule.jar` e usá-la no `MyWebProject.war` eu consigo ver os efeitos colaterais (e.g., `isDone() == true`) mas nada é escrito para o `server.log`.

O que eu estou esquecendo? Eu preciso de alguma outra dependência além do slf4j?

---

**Crosspost:** Pergunta original - [SOen - How to log with slf4j from within a jboss module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33223088/664577)

Comment: De cara eu chutaria que o nível de log está diferente. Para ter certeza disso eu trocaria o `info` por `error` e repetiria o teste com o módulo.

Comment: Segundo pensamento: será que para funcionar não seria necessário também adicionar como dependência do módulo uma implementação de log, como o `log4`? [Esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23080264/1683070) do SO lista alguns módulos a serem excluídos para que a aplicação use o próprio sistema de log, portanto talvez seja necessário incluí-las para usar o sistema de log do JBoss.

Comment: Uma terceira alternativa seria iniciar o JBoss em modo de depuração e investigar o que ocorre dentro da rotina de log. Não resolve o problema mas pode dar uma pista do que está faltando.

Comment: Olá @utluiz, obrigado pela pronta atenção (como sempre). O nível padrão de logging está para INFO no servidor. Mesmo assim eu tentei subir para ERROR (e, do lado contrário, setar os níveis de logging para TRACE), nada funcionou. Eu também penso que estou precisando de mais alguns módulos aí, só não consigo descobrir quais... Vou tentar o *remote debugging*.

Comment: Pra tentar simular aqui: qual versão do JBoss/WildFly está usando?

Comment: Olá Bruno: Wildfly 9.0.1 final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para referência futura, meu problema não tinha nada a ver com *logging*. A receita acima funciona como esperado. De fato, eu sofri devido a uma informação falsa: meu `module.xml` original nunca foi realmente usado. Eu estava carregando uma classe velha com o mesmo nome em outro módulo. Essa versão velha da classe não tinha *logging* e não deveria estar lá para começo de conversa.

De qualquer forma, eu acho que a  causa raiz do meu problema (além de falta de atenção) foi um pequeno *bug* na `jboss-cli`.

Eu estava fazendo *deploy* do `mymodule` com o seguinte comando:

```
module add --name=com.mycompany.mymodule \
            --resources=MyModule.jar \
            --dependencies=org.slf4j \
            --main-class=com.mycompany.mymodule.Main
```

Esse comando estava gerando um `module.xml` como esse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mycompany.mymodule">

    <main-class value="com.mycompany.mymodule.Main"/>

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="MyModule.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Quando eu finalmente consegui fazer meu projeto web tentar carregar o `mymodule` ele falhou com uma *stack trace* como essa:

```
18:45:59,999 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.MyWebProject.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.MyWebProject.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.MyWebProject.war.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from C:\opt\server\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\modules\com\mycompany\mymodule\main\module.xml
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:150)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:127)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder$1.run(LocalModuleFinder.java:150)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder$1.run(LocalModuleFinder.java:144)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleFinder.findModule(LocalModuleFinder.java:144)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.findModule(ModuleLoader.java:452)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:355)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:302)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadExportedModule(ModuleLoader.java:313)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:326)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ServiceModuleLoader.preloadModule(ServiceModuleLoader.java:149)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:234)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:74)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.xml.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected content of type 'element start' named 'main-class', text is: '<main-class value="com.mycompany.mymodule.Main"/>' (position: START_TAG seen ...n-class value="com.mycompany.mymodule.Main"/>... @5:54) 
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.unexpectedContent(ModuleXmlParser.java:179)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseMainClass(ModuleXmlParser.java:620)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleContents(ModuleXmlParser.java:445)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:261)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:148)
    ... 18 more
```

Dando uma olhada no `module-1_1.xsd` eu descobri que o elemento `main-class` estava esperando um atributo `name` ao invés de um atributo `value`. Então eu modifiquei o `module.xml` manualmente para:

```
<main-class name="com.mycompany.mymodule.Main"/>
```

Depois de reiniciar o WildFly e redeployar meu projeto web tudo funcionou como esperado.

Comment: Este é um daqueles momentos de felicidade em descobrir um erro "bobo" após o desespero de esgotar todas as possibilidades e achar que vai ter que mudar toda a arquitetura, vendor ou tecnologia para não ficar louco. :)